# Nuclear norm regularization of symmetric matrix

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, trace, regularization, nuclear-norm

I have an optimization problem of the form

$$\min_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}}  g(X) - \lambda \|X\|_{*}$$

where function $g$ is convex and differentiable. I would like to use proximal gradient descent to solve this. How do I handle the constraint that $X$ be symmetric? Or, formulated differently, how do I make sure that $X$ remains symmetric throughout my updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do this is not to treat the symmetry of $X$ as a constraint. Rather, it is to make the space of symmetric matrices *the domain of the function*.

So for example, treat this not as a function of $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, but rather as a function of $X\in\mathcal{S}^n$, the set of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices.

The most important consequence of this way of thinking is that the gradient $\nabla g(X)$ *will itself be a symmetric matrix*. So you have to be careful in how you compute the gradient so that this is correctly achieved. For example, if $g(X)=\tfrac{1}{2}\|X-P\|_F^2$, where $P$ is symmetric, then $\nabla g(X) = X - P$.

Comment: Sure, just use $\l1$-style shrinkage on the eigenvalues.